# How to migrate DynamoDb to RDS (Aurora)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database-migration, amazon-aurora

I'm quite new in AWS. I have a running database on DynamoDB and now want to migrate to Amazon RDS (Aurora)? I am not getting any clue how to do that? Welcome for any kind of help or assessment.
I also need to consider the downtime and transformation tools for NoSQL to Relational DB.

Comment: Did you have find a way to resolve this? I meet this problem too.

Answer (score 5):

One method you could do, is to use [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) in order to export the dynamodb data into S3, and then import the data from S3 into the relational database of your choice.

More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html

Comment: @Icehorn- where will I do the data transformation if I use AWS pipeline.